# How to configure an external package into Apache Spark?

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am building a Python script executed using **spark-submit** command to retrieve data from MongoDB collection and process fetched data to generate analytics. I am utilizing MongoDB Spark connector to query a MongoDB collection using `--packages` option.

But I need to configure package into Apache Spark and execute Python script using spark submit command without `--packages` option.

Comment: Why do you avoid to use --packages option? Just ask if we can walk around it.

Answer (score 1):

From http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html:

> For Python, you can use the --py-files argument of spark-submit to add .py, .zip or .egg files to be distributed with your application. If you depend on multiple Python files we recommend packaging them into a .zip or .egg.

So you could write your own layer of data loading logic. However, using a ready-made package has lots of advantages. Maybe you could explain why you cannot use `--packages`?

EDIT

Based on the chat, the only reason PO couldn't use `--packages` is his `jar` for mongodb is stored locally (and of course not in `$PATH`). In this case, providing `--repositories /PATH/TO/JAR` should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question.I need to invoke spark application from php script and spark application is not invoked upon specifying --packages option .Hence I need to configure package into apache spark itself.

Comment: How could "spark application is not invoked upon specifying --packages option" happen?

Comment: Following is php code snippet                         $result=shell_exec('./bin/spark-submit --master local[*] --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.10:1.0.0 examples/src/main/python/demo.py'); 
print_r($result);

Comment: Spark application is invoked in shell when --packages options in specified into spark-submit command but not from external application

Comment: When you run your PHP snippet what error does it give?

Comment: Upon execution of spark-submit command through php code snippet it doesn't return any output to php script

Comment: And without `--packages` would it run? I think this is no longer a Spark problem. You could use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to capture the error message in PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121534/discussion-between-rubin-porwal-and-shuaiyuan).